# Outputting HTML using Undescore templates

Tags: underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I have this is in a JavaScript object

```
"title": "Company<br />UK Sales &amp; Manufacturing"
```

then in my underscore template I have

```
h2 <%- _.unescape(rc.title) %>
```

The following is rendered

```
Company<br />UK Sales & Manufacturing
```

Any idea how I get the html to render correctly

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

From the [fine manual](http://underscorejs.org/#template):

> Template functions can both interpolate values, using `<%= … %>`, as well as execute arbitrary JavaScript code, with `<% … %>`. If you wish to interpolate a value, and have it be HTML-escaped, use `<%- … %>`.

So `<%= ... %>` doesn't do any HTML escaping by on its own and if you have an HTML snippet that should go straight on the page then:

```
<%= rc.title %>
```

`<%- ... %>` will HTML-encode incoming text (i.e. `<br />` becomes `&lt;br /&gt;`) and [`_.unescape`](http://underscorejs.org/#unescape) is for decoding HTML-encoded text (i.e. `&amp;` becomes `&`) so you don't want to use those. Straight interpolation is all you need.